# passing text field data to a textarea in a same page

Tags: codeigniter

I am using four input fields. After completing all the fields, the entered data will pass to the lower text area. How can it possible?

Please help me.

My view page is

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>   

<div class="controls">
    <label class="housename">housename</label> 
    <input type="text" id="house number" name="house number" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div> 

<div class="horizontal-form">

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="firstName"></label> 
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">Street</label> 
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">city</label> 
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Contact Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
    <textarea rows="3" name="address" class="span5 m-wrap" title=" Address"></textarea>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: First, div's are not closed properly. I really doubt it is properly aligned. Second, this is what I understood...you want Name, house_number, Street and City values to be populated in textarea(address). Am i right ??

Comment: yes thats what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code, which worked for me

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="housename">housename</label> 
    <input type="text" id="house_number" name="house_number" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div> 

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">Street</label> 
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">city</label> 
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Contact Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" class="span5 m-wrap" title=" Address"></textarea>  
    </div>  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("input").on('change',function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var house_number = $('#house_number').val();    // you need to change the id and name attributes for housename.
    var street = $('#street').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var data = name+","+house_number+","+street+","+city;

    $("#address").html(data);    // please add id attribute for textarea
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add jquery library in your view file ??

Comment: Edit my post with complete code, which worked for me...you can remove the jquery library if it is added in the header

Comment: for one input field it works like this `$('.class of any of the field').on('change', function () {
            document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = $(this).val();
            
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: 
    
        name

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="housename">housename</label> 
    <input type="text" id="house_number" name="house_number" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div> 

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">Street</label> 
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <label class="fieldname">city</label> 
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="m-wrap span4 horizontal-form" placeholder="">  
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Contact Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" class="span5 m-wrap" title=" Address"></textarea>  
    </div>  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('input').on('change,function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var house_number = $('#house_number').val();    // you need to change the id and name attributes for housename.
    var street = $('#street').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var data = name+","+house_number+","+street+","+city;

    $("#address").html(data);    // please add id attribute for textarea
});
</script>
```